# How to change the order of the primeFaces picklist buttons

Tags: button, primefaces

Is there an easy way to change the order of the sort and move buttons from the PrimeFaces picklist? 
For better usability i need the buttons to be in this order:

Sort:

```
all up
up
down
all down
```

and for moving:

```
all to the right
right
left
all to the left
```

I am just the one who implements a dummy page and someone else has to implement as a PrimeFaces Component what i am designing here. So i don't want it to be a impossible task for the programmer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built-in buttonTemplate feature, you can change the order with css though.

Code:

```
.ui-picklist-button-add {
    position:relative;
    top:25px;
}

.ui-picklist-button-add-all {
    position:relative;
    top:-40px;
}
```

-> This is what 'Optimus Prime' says. His answer in the Prime Faces Forum on my question

Comment: your solution would surely work, too. But this one is more elegant.

Comment: yup , much more , that's why I gave +1

Answer (score 1):

you can try doing it with jQuery like that : [JavaScript moving element in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363650/javascript-moving-element-in-the-dom)

Use firebug to find out all the classes of the buttons and its containers

for example try `jQuery(".ui-picklist-target-controls .ui-picklist-button-move-top").insertAfter(".ui-picklist-target-controls .ui-picklist-button-move-top");`

If want to patch the primefaces jar look at the PickListRenderer.java file look where they use the `encodeButton` method , and just re order the buttons...

although you will have to re patch it each time you'll want to upgrade

Comment: and there's no easy option for the primeFaces picklist to change that? Is it really just take the component as it is or write your own one? I'm confused they didn't consider it to be more intuitive to have the buttons ordered in another way.

Comment: they offer custom titles for the buttons and the ability to display/hide them... you can always open a new feature ticket...

Answer (score 1):

I am the same problem but still got pixel issues with different screens.

Using flexbox should be better than px change:

```
.ui-picklist-buttons-cell{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ui-picklist-button-add {
  order:2;
}
.ui-picklist-button-add-all {
  order:1;
}
.ui-picklist-button-remove {
  order:3;
}
.ui-picklist-button-remove-all {
  order:4;
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/Frank_Worker/pen/abzYmYr

Comment: Cool, great to see this solution..!