# How Do I Shift The Parent Of Element Fixed Value Down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider the code:

```html
<div id="block">
  <div id="sub_block">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    
  </div>
</div>
    
<div class="click">Click Me!</div>
```

I want that whenever someone clicks ".click", the parent #sub_block is shifted down 2 spans.

**Click 1:**

```html
<div id="block">    
  <span></span>
  <span></span>

  <div id="sub_block">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**Click 2:**

```html
<div id="block"> 
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <div id="sub_block">   
    <span></span>    
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>   
  </div>
</div>
```

And so on. And when `span<=0;` It should no longer work or stop. Any suggestions? **jQuery accepted.**

Comment: Show us what you have tried in jsFiddle.

Comment: I'm able to unwrap the parent with .unwrap() on click. But how do I wrap the same parent after a specific number of spans?

Comment: Have you tried with **parentNode**?

Comment: You might want to see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363650/javascript-moving-element-in-the-dom).

Comment: ^ No. Actually I don't want to swap the divs. I want to bring the parent div a little down or take 2 child spans out of parent div on every click.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach:

```
var $subBlock = $('#sub_block'),
    $clicker  = $('.click');

var moveProcessor = function() {
  var $spansToMove = $subBlock.children('span').slice(0, 2);
  if ($spansToMove.length < 2) {
    $clicker.off('click', moveProcessor);
  }
  else {
    $spansToMove.insertBefore($subBlock);
  }
}

$clicker.on('click', moveProcessor);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ALwdM/). It's quite simple really: at each click we grab the first two `<span>`-children of our $subBlock; if there's at least 2, we move it (with `insertBefore()`) from inside this block to outside. And if there's less than 2, we just switch this handler off.

Apparently, if there's an odd number of `<span>`, this code will leave the last one in subBlock. If that's not required, just change the condition in `if` block to `if ($spansToMove.length === 0)` (or just `if (!($spansToMove.length))`).

Answer (score 1):

**Its Quite simple Logic** Question is how you want to implement it ?

Here is the simplest Way to make you understand the logic: **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nevocura/1/edit)**

```
$(function(){     
  $(".click").on('click',function(){
    var arrSpan = $("#sub_block span");
    if(arrSpan.length) {
      arrSpan.eq(0).insertBefore($("#sub_block"));            
    }
    arrSpan = $("#sub_block span");
    if(arrSpan.length) {
      arrSpan.eq(0).insertBefore($("#sub_block"));            
    }
  });      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

another approach

```
$(".click").click(function () {
  $("#sub_block").before($("#sub_block span:eq(0)"));
  $("#sub_block").before($("#sub_block span:eq(1)"));
});
```

In each click, it will get first 2 children  of `subblock` and move it to the parent block.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xUjmh/12/)

**Edit**

```
$(".click").click(function () {
  $("#sub_block").before($("#sub_block span:eq(0)"));
  $("#sub_block").before($("#sub_block span:eq(0)"));
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xUjmh/14/)

Comment: @j08691 ohh you are right. I've edited the answer and the fiddle. The problem with the first code is that, after appending the first span, the second span will be the first child of subdiv. Which causes third span to be append if i try to take the 2nd child..

Answer (score 0):

```
function shift() {
  var div_elem = document.getElementById('sub_block');
  var master = document.getElementById('block');
  if(div_elem.childNodes.length>0) {
    var elem1 = div_elem.childNodes[0];
    var elem2 = div_elem.childNodes[1];
    elem1.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(elem1);
    elem2.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(elem2);
    master.appendChild(elem1);
    master.appendChild(elem2);
  }
}
```

I hope this help you

Comment: You don't have to remove the nodes explicitly, you can just append them to the new parent. Anyways, it doesn't produce the output the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure and very simple DOM solution, using [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore):

```
var block = document.getElementByID('block');
var sub_block = document.getElementByID('sub_block');

document.querySelector('.click').onclick = function() {  
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (sub_block.children[0]) {
      block.inserBefore(sub_block.children[0], sub_block);
    }
  }
};
```

On each click we simply take the first two children of `sub_block` and insert them before it.