# Sort DIVs alphabetically without destroying and recreating them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to be able to sort a bunch of `div` elements on my page with the click of a button.

All of them have simple text content, for example:

```
<div class='sortme'>
    CCC
</div>
<div class='sortme'>
    AAA
</div>
<div class='sortme'>
    BBB
</div>
<div class='sortme'>
    DDD
</div>
```

When the user clicks a button, they should be rearranged in alphabetical order. Obviously there's a number of ways to do this, most obviously we can get all the contents into an array, sort the array and recreate the HTML based on that.

This is an example of such a solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/C2heg/

However, this wouldn't play nice with a lot of code already being used, and I was hoping to be able to simply move the divs around without doing anything destructive. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript moving element in the DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363650/javascript-moving-element-in-the-dom)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Sort the element array with [**sort()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
2. Reattach(in their sorted state) with [**appendTo()**](https://api.jquery.com/appendto/)

```js
$('.sortme').sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.textContent < b.textContent) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='sortme'>
  CCC
</div>
<div class='sortme'>
  AAA
</div>
<div class='sortme'>
  BBB
</div>
<div class='sortme'>
  DDD
</div>
```

Comment: `detach()` is useless i guess and you should append it to specific container, not the body. BTW, i'd trim the `textContent`, just in case

Comment: @A.Wolff, uhhhh nice observation. Thanks for the tip

Comment: simplification:   $('.sortme').sort(function(a, b) {  return a.textContent < b.textContent ? -1 : 1  }
}).appendTo('body');

Answer (score 9):

Can be done pretty simply even without jQuery

```
function sortThem(s) {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.body.querySelectorAll(s)).sort(function sort (ea, eb) {
        var a = ea.textContent.trim();
        var b = eb.textContent.trim();
        if (a.textContent < b.textContent) return -1;
        if (a.textContent > b.textContent) return 1;
        return 0;
    }).forEach(function(div) {
        div.parentElement.appendChild(div);
    });
}
// call it like this
sortThem('div.sortme');
```

**element**.appendChild(x) adds x as the last child of **element**, if x exists in the DOM, it is moved from it's current location, so, no need for any gymnastics to remove it in one place and add it in t'other

Comment: @PixelPimp - huh? 5 year old answer, and you quote the last two lines of the code as a comment ... is there a point?

Answer (score 2):

Use append.

```
var $divs = $("div.box");

$("div.box").on("click", function (e) {
    alert("I'm an original");
});

$('#alphBnt').on('click', function () {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("h1").text() > $(b).find("h1").text();
    });

    alphabeticallyOrderedDivs.each(function (i, item) {
        $("#container").append(item);
    });
});

$('#numBnt').on('click', function () {
    var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("h2").text() > $(b).find("h2").text();
    });

    numericallyOrderedDivs.each(function (i, item) {
        $("#container").append(item);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/343/)