# Sort divs based on <p> content of div's childs [PureJS only]

Tags: html, css, sorting

How can I sort divs inside wrapper based on its childs content **with pure javascript.**

I have this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/55mfj7oe/

How can I sort `.item` elements (purple) based on the divs inside it by clicking buttons under wrapper.

I found solution with jQuery but I'm looking for pureJS only.

Comment: What's the jQuery solution you found?

Comment: Did you search for an answer - this has been done soooo many times, like this http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31267241/295783

Comment: mplungjan - I wrote PureJS only.
Darren Sweeney - I searched, most of the solutions are jQuery.

Comment: Why do you need a pureJS solution? jQuery makes your life so much easier. Especially with this kind of things. If you want to write this with pure javascript you are going to have write quite some code.

Comment: Because I dont understand jQuery. Can anyone do it with jQuery (my Fiddle) so I can check it?

Comment: Yep @user3734782 see my answer below ;)

Comment: Did you see the actual answer I linked to. It is JS only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example based on your JSFIDDLE. You can find this example [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/wjLgh7ab/).

Let me explain something about the code so that you might understand it better.
First you had this Javascript for setting the CSS class of each button:

```
var sortByYear = document.getElementsByClassName('sortbtn')[0];
var sortByName = document.getElementsByClassName('sortbtn')[1];
var sortByLname = document.getElementsByClassName('sortbtn')[2];
sortByYear.style.background = 'red';
sortByName.style.background = 'cyan';
sortByLname.style.background = 'yellow';
```

First off all, I think for coding purpose it easier if you give each button a different name. In that case it easier to distuingush which button is clicked. In my example I add for each button a different class. Then with jQuery I can set the `background-color` like this:

```
$('.sortyear').css('background-color','red');
$('.sortfirstname').css('background-color','orange');
$('.sortlastname').css('background-color','yellow');
```

For the sorting part the jQuery code is also quite easy. Look at the code for sorting the divs on year:

```
var $divs = $("div.item");

$('.sortyear').on('click', function () {        
    var sortbyyear = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find(".item-year").text() > $(b).find(".item-year").text();
    });
    $(".content").html(sortbyyear);
});
```

First a variable is needed to store each item. Than I check if the button with class: `.sortyear` is clicked and if it is clicked then I create a function inside the on click function.

Let me explain the inside function in more detail:

```
var sortbyyear = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).find(".item-year").text() > $(b).find(".item-year").text();
});
```

In this function I sort all the `div.items` based on the value that is found within the `.item-year` object. Then I check whether the value of the first `div.item` is bigger then the value of the second `div.item`

In the end when all the comparison is done you have to append it to your content div. You can set the HTML of the content by using the variable where you set the sorted items `sortbyyear`:

```
$(".content").html(sortbyyear);
```

That's it. Keep in mind that I created three functions (which seems like a large bunk of code but I did not want to make it to complicate for you). If you still have any questions let me know