# Sorting divs alphabetically in its own parent (due to many lists)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is a follow up to this question: [How can I sort elements alphabetically by text content and bring next div if existing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74892377/how-can-i-sort-elements-alphabetically-by-text-content-and-bring-next-div-if-exi)

The problem I ran into is that there is multiple lists and when apply the correct answer in the previous question all the sorted divs get appended to all parent divs (so they get multiple apended divs). Tried to solve this by make it append to its parent but couldent make it work. If somebody wants to help I would appreciate it.

**Problem: All parent divs get all appended divs.**

```js
$('.sort').sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.textContent < b.textContent) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}).each((index, el) => {
    const hidden = $(el).next();

    if (hidden.hasClass('hidden')) {
        $(el).add(hidden).appendTo('.parent');
    } else {
        $(el).appendTo('.parent');
    }

});

$(".btn_expand").on('click', function () {
  $(this).next("div").toggle();
});
```

```css
.btn_expand{background:red;}  
.hidden{display: none;}
.parent{border: 1px solid blue; padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="btn_expand sort">CCC</div>
  <div class="hidden">Hidden content shown by press CCC</div>
  <div class="btn_no_expand sort">EEE</div>
  <div class="btn_no_expand sort">AAA</div>
  <div class="btn_no_expand sort">DDD</div>
  <div class="btn_expand sort">BBB</div>
  <div class="hidden">Hidden content shown by press BBB</div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="btn_expand sort">CCC</div>
  <div class="hidden">Hidden content shown by press CCC</div>
  <div class="btn_no_expand sort">EEE</div>
  <div class="btn_no_expand sort">AAA</div>
  <div class="btn_no_expand sort">DDD</div>
  <div class="btn_expand sort">BBB</div>
  <div class="hidden">Hidden content shown by press BBB</div>
</div>
```

What an awesome code editor Stackoverflow has these days! Never seen it before.

Thanks for answers. Sorry for bad engelsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you have to iterate the `.parent` elements, and then select the `.sort` elements below the currently iterated parent. For that you can use the second argument of the `$` function.

You should also call `appendTo` with that parent as argument.

I made some other, less essential changes:

```js
$('.parent').each(function(_, parent) {
  $('.sort', parent).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent);
  }).each((index, el) => {
      const hidden = $(el).next();
      $(el).appendTo(parent);
      if (hidden.hasClass('hidden')) {
          hidden.appendTo(parent);
      }
  });
});

$(".btn_expand").on('click', function () {
  $(this).next("div").toggle();
});
```

```css
.btn_expand{background:red;}  
.hidden{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="btn_expand sort">CCC</div>
  <div class="hidden">Hidden content shown by press CCC</div>
  <div class="btn_no_expand sort">EEE</div>
  <div class="btn_no_expand sort">AAA</div>
  <div class="btn_no_expand sort">DDD</div>
  <div class="btn_expand sort">BBB</div>
  <div class="hidden">Hidden content shown by press BBB</div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="btn_expand sort">CCC</div>
  <div class="hidden">Hidden content shown by press CCC</div>
  <div class="btn_no_expand sort">EEE</div>
  <div class="btn_no_expand sort">AAA</div>
  <div class="btn_no_expand sort">DDD</div>
  <div class="btn_expand sort">BBB</div>
  <div class="hidden">Hidden content shown by press BBB</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked excellent! Thank you! Quick question, is there any way to put one children div always at bottom if adding a class somehow? In the lists there is "Other" selection, and would be nice to always be able to put those last in every list. Thank you again.

Comment: I created a new post since the answer to this question was accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74899326/keep-div-always-as-bottom-when-multiple-gets-appended