# Two column different position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to do something not very hard but I don't know how to do.

Now here I have the version for mobile how it looks now.

Mobile version it looks like this:
[image]

And here it's how I want to looks:
[image]

Here I have the code.

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
                    $res = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                    $i = 0;
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))             
                   {
                   if($i%2==0)
                   {
                  echo "<div class='row' style='margin-right:0; margin-left:0'>



            <div class='col-md-6' style='padding:0;''>
                <img class='image-width img-responsive' src='images/my_img/".$row['primary_img']."' />
                        </div><!--/span-->


                <div class='col-md-6 find-content' style='margin-top:8%;'>
                   <img src='images/my_img/".$row['icon']."'/>
                    <p style='font-family:GothamBold;color:#ec1940;font-size:1.5em; margin-top:5%;'>".$row['title']."</p>
                    <p style='width:50%;margin-left:25%;' class='text'>".$row['text']."</p>
                  <a class='a-button'  href='atractions.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Hi</a>            
                </div><!--/span-->
                </div><!--/row -->";
             }
        else
        {
            echo " <div class='row' style='margin-right:0; margin-left:0'>

        <div class='col-md-6 find-content' style='margin-top:10%;'>
         <img src='img/descopera/icons/".$row['icon']."'/>
            <p style='font-family:GothamBold;color:#ec1940;font-size:1.5em; margin-top:5%;'>".$row['title']."</p>
            <p style='width:50%;margin-left:25%;' class='text-descopera'>".$row['text']."</p>
          <a class='a-button'  href='atractions.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Hi</a>    
        </div><!--/span-->


         <div class='col-md-6' style='padding:0;'>
              <img class='image-width img-responsive' src='images/my_img/".$row['primary_img']."' />
            </div><!--/span-->

        </div><!--/row--> ";
        }   
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: Can we have your CSS too ? And working fiddle would be perfect for us to try things before giving you an answer :)

Comment: Ok, so..class="find-content" CSS => .find-content{max-height:auto; max-width: 100%; text-align: center;} | class="image-width" => .image-width{width:100%;}

Comment: This is possible using flexbox but without knowing your specific HTML we cannot state if that would apply in your circumstances. We'd need a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I copied again the code and I used class of bootstrap named 'visible'

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe there is a simple CSS solution for changing the order of DOM elements. You need Javascript for that.

Revising my answer.. I would do it by writing out element 3 two times - before and after element 2. And then toggle display of the duplicate elements depending on breakpoint. (this answer only applies if the elements are fairly simple as duplicate markup is less than desirable).

(A side note: I would really recommend that you look in to some templating instead of echoing out the markup like that, Twig for instance)

Comment: Thanks for answer! What do you think about this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363650/javascript-moving-element-in-the-dom

Comment: Also a possibility, but not pretty either. I think the way I would do something like that is write out the the third element twice (before and after element 2) - and then toggle visibility of the duplicate elements depending on which breakpoint you hit.